# Generalized solution to force equilibria with multiple particles?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

Computer scientist here, pardon my lack of terminology.

Let's say that we have $N$ particles living in (for sake of simplicity) 1D space at a point $P_i$, with the mass of $M_i$. Lets further assume that each particle exerts a repulsive force equivalent to $\frac{M_i}{x-P_i}$.

(Let's further assume these particles don't exert any forces on each other and are stationary)

What are the points at which there is a force equilibrium?

Given these constraints we can derive that there will be exactly one force equilibrium between any two neighbouring particles (given that force approaches infinity as $x$ approaches any of the particles)

I further know that solving for these force equilibria equates to solving:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{M_i}{x-P_i} = 0$$

How do you solve such equation?

EDIT - here is a diagram for clarity (x is the location of the particle and y is its mass) - in this case I am using 4 particles.

[image]

Comment: You have one equation for n+1 unknowns $P_i$ there is no solution , but you can solve this equation for x

Comment: Pi is the position of each particle, right? what is x?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny x is a point in 1D space

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is better is you write:

$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{M_i}{P_j-P_i} = 0, \quad j=1,..,n$

This system will never reach equilibrium. The particles at the extremes are always pushed away, and in the end all particles will end up moving apart from each other. Think about them as if they were all positively charged particles.

Note: